# LaTeX (beamer) — Is there a way to suppress the caption label of “Figure X:” or “Table X:”?

Tags: beamer, captions

I am making a beamer presentation of someone else's research paper (so I don't have the original tex code). I am using pdfs of tables in the presentation but wanted to cut out all of the original captions, which can be a bit wordy for a slideshow, and simply label them with either "Table X" or "Figure X" along with the title.

So I'd like to suppress automatically inserted caption label (otherwise it would say "Figure: Table I", and so on). If I put the title/label without the `\caption{}` function, then I have to fight with word wrapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless each member of the audience is expected to have a printed copy of the paper to follow while you do your presentation, I think it doesn't make a lot of sense to number your Figures/Tables in the presentation. How about just keeping something like "Figure: Some short title" with the standard captioning facilities from beamer?

If for some reason you *really, really* want to include the number of each figure/table as it appeared on the original document, you could manually redefine `\figurename` before issuing each `\caption` command to include the appropriate number. For example:

```
\begin{figure}
% your figure goes here

\def\figurename{Figure 1}
\caption{Some short title}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thanks, Juan! Works like a charm! The audience will have the paper, so I'd like for the audience (really seminar participants) to be able to follow along easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

According to Section 11.6 in the [beamer user guide](http://www.tug.org/teTeX/tetex-texmfdist/doc/latex/beamer/beameruserguide.pdf), you can add the following lines to the preambles of your latex code to meet the requirements:

```
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
```

Then, you'll see the figures and tables are numbered with prefix like "Figure X: " or "Table Y: ". And I think it is the most elegant way in satisfying the original requirements in this post.

Answer (score 5):

This to me seems a better/cleaner solution:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,labelsep=none}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to load the `caption` package to do this in `beamer`; the `beamer` way of doing this is to set the appropriate templates: `\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption}
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina you are completely right, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina it seems once e.g. the subcaption package is loaded, the way through \setbeamertemplate no longer works but the one through \captionsetup still does.

Comment: @anonymous but why use `subcaption` with `beamer`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina For subfigures likes http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Latex_example_subfig.png. According to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats that's what one should use these days instead of the packages subfigure and subfig.

Comment: @anonymous of course, `subfigure` shouldn't be used anymore (and this has been so for many years now) since it's obsolete; `subfig` can still be used in a document (the very same author of the caption packages has said this in  this same site), but you don't need any packages for subfigures in a *presentation*.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I use subfigures quite often in my presentations. Should I not?

Comment: @anonymous well, you can use subfigures, but do you really need a package for subfigures in a presentation? I mean, in a presentation you need basically a label and caption, and to produce these you don't *really* need a dedicated package; I am obviously considering that a presentation has a different nature from other kind of documents (a paper, or a book, for example). I would like to explain in more detail my remark here, but unfortunately comments are not the best place to do so.