# How to remove figure caption prefix "figure" in beamer

Tags: beamer, captions

I am trying to remove the caption prefix, "Figure", for my figures in beamer. I tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3842322/957560) but it made no difference.

Heres a minimum working example:
As you can see, I have included the `caption` package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[super,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}

% \usepackage{makeidx}
% \usepackage{sidecap}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
%\setbeamercolor{structure}{bg=yellow, fg=black}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}


\logo{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{logo1}%
\hspace{\dimexpr\paperwidth-4cm}
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{logo2}%
}%


\begin{document}


\title[PT]{Presentation Title}
\author[Author1]{List of Authors}
\institute[Univ]{University Name}

\begin{frame} % Cover slide
\titlepage
\end{frame}



\frame{
\frametitle{Evaporating liquid film, G=0.0, S=100, M=35.1, Pr=7.02, E=0.0001, R=0}


\begin{figure}
 \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.21]{/home/userid/Research/Dissertation/wigner/montage_evap/Evap_zg_2wl}
    \caption{Wavenumber k=2}
 \end{center}
\end{figure}



}
```

Comment: Have you seen this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3303/18674 ?

Comment: @BenediktBauer This will still attach the word "Figure" before my caption. I am trying to get rid of the word "Figure"

Comment: Not using a figure environment maybe? Put it inside a block etc.

Comment: @percusse But how can I not use a figure env. as I need figures? Plus I have 80+ pages of figures. this doesnt sound like a fun exercise! `:P`

Comment: figure environment is not needed to include figures. Just use `\includegraphics...` directly and you'll see what I mean. You don't need floats in `beamer` as they are placed directly on the same slides..

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Renew caption template

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}

\frame{
\begin{figure}
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}
}

\end{document}
```

No need to load any other packages. You may even add some fancy stuff like a

```
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth, sep=.2ex]{block body}\insertcaption%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
```

Which basically gives you a colored box around the caption (when a color-theme is used).

You can use :

```
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[default]
```

if you want to switch back the parameter to its default value, for example if you want the change to be only local.

Comment: OK... so what does this to?

Comment: Removes "Figure". You will see the effect when you compile the code.

Comment: somehow this didn't work, I still see the "Figure" prefix.

Comment: @JinghaoShi, this way doesn't work if you use packages like `caption`. In that case, see @azetina's answer.

Comment: Make sure you're not using the `subcaption` package either.

Answer (score 71):

You can use the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}% redefines the caption setup of the figures environment in the beamer class.

\begin{document}
\frame{
\begin{figure}
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}\caption{test}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
c&c
\end{tabular}
\end{table}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that since I am only redefining the caption style for figures the rest are left intact as defined by the `beamer` class.

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: @drN Why? Isn't that what wanted? That is, to remove the Figure and numbering from the caption?

Comment: perhaps my question should have been clearer: Yes you understand it right. I wanted to remove the prefix "Figure". I had already been able to remove the number. However, `\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}` did not work. I am not sure why.

Comment: @drN Probably you had to recompile. That is, delete all `.aux` files created by the compilation and then compile again with the new setting. Just saying.

Comment: Thanks, this is the one that worked for me. Classic latex: works but only if you're using some random package X.

Answer (score 41):

The solution is very simple. Just put the caption below the \includegraphics... command with a double left slash. You don't need to use the caption command, only if you need to number figures, which is note very common in a presentation:

```
\centering
\includegraphics...
\\ <your caption here>
```

Comment: This is the simplest option, IMHO.

Comment: Finally. This worked for my Document class on Texmaker with minipage where everything was failing.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - the text under this approach did not match the size of the caption text.

Answer (score 12):

None of the answers worked for me, I had the same problem. I tried this one in the preamble and it does the job requested:

```
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,labelsep=none}
```

Comment: This *is* covered in [another answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82462/5764) (apart from `labelsep=none`), so why do you say "[n]one of the answers worked for me"?

Comment: the only working solution!

Comment: I tried this and it added a blank slide at the start of my beamer slides. Any idea why?

Answer (score 9):

I've been having trouble with the caption package in Beamer, and the options above using this package weren't working for me.

However, this in the preamble seemed to do the trick:

```
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption}
```

Comment: I also had some troubles with caption package in beamer. This solution is simple and does the job

Comment: Same with me...

Comment: This did not work for me

Answer (score 3):

Do not use the commands `\begin{figure}`, `\caption` and `\end{figure}`. 
Just use `\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{fig.eps}`

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui. It is also better to post solutions that compile, a "[minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)", as this makes it easier for people to appreciate and use your answer. This said, I don't think that you have answered the OPs question...

Answer (score 3):

I use the `caption*` command instead of `caption`, which removes the prefix in the Beamer slides.

Comment: This did not work for me.