# \usepackage{caption} with beamer gives Missing number treated as zero

Tags: beamer, captions, beamer-metropolis

If I use the caption package with beamer frames, I get a 'missing number treated as zero'.

The following compiles with texlive, but if I uncomment the `\usepackage{caption}` line, I get the error.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

% \usepackage{caption}

\title{Error}
\author{Author}
\institute{Stack Overflow}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame} \frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
            \caption{Duck\footnote[frame]{Duck Duck}}
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
            \caption{Duck\footnote[frame]{Duck Duck}}
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. The error is from the `[frame]` option added to the macro `\footnote[frame]{}`. Removing this option will make it work : `\caption{Duck\footnote{Duck Duck}}`. Where did you get this `[frame]` option?

Comment: I think in general `beamer` is incompatible with `caption`. `beamer` already provides caption-related templates to control style of `\caption`, see [`beamer` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), sec. 12.6. Hence you can avoid loading `caption` by make use of those beamer caption templates.

Comment: @AndréC `\footnote[frame]` is supported by `beamer` to indicate "this footnote should be typeset at the bottom of the frame", see beamer manual, sec. 12.12. Furthermore, although no errors, using `\caption{Duck \footnote{Duck Duck}}` produces wrong output, in which the width of column is wider than expected. From `beamer` issue #268, [Incompatibility of beamer with caption package](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/268), it seems the compatibility issue is never solved.

Comment: On the `caption` side, it _do_ fixed compatibility reported issues with `beamer`, see [here](https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=closed&search=beamer). So if one can reduce the problem to be `caption`-related, an issue to https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues is welcome. @AndréC I checked again, the too-wide column issue is reproducible even without `caption`. Sorry for my mis-judgement.

Comment: I wanted my captions to appear without the labels, so I was using caption package. I removed it and set `\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}` as mentioned in this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82460/220753

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: This _is_ an compatibility issue, and I've reported to `caption`. See https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/84.

Comment: @oponkork Or you can use `\caption{Dock\footnotemark}` and then `\footnotetext[1]{Duck Duck}` outside of `columns` environment.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thank you for all this exciting information.

Answer (score 1):

Some updates:

Thanks to Axel Sommerfeldt, the author of `caption`, this [compatibility issue](https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/84) has been **fixed** in [`caption` 2020-07-20](https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/releases/CTAN_2020-07-20), and the update is already installable in TeX Live. MiKTeX users might need to wait.

This update even allows the direct use of `\footnote` in multi-line `\caption`, which will produces two copies of footnote text at the bottom of frame in plain `beamer`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} \frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{Duck\footnote[frame]{Duck Duck}}
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{Duck Duck Duck Duck Duck Duck\footnote[frame]{Duck Duck}}
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]